# Notepad++ Merge two lines

Tags: merge, notepad++

I would like to merge every two line into one and adding a TAB in between.

**Original**
STAN LEE: There are over
six billion people on Earth.
Genetically, most of us are
almost the same.
But every now and then,
a mutation occurs.

**Result**
STAN LEE: There are over         six billion people on Earth.
Genetically, most of us are       almost the same.
But every now and then,       a mutation occurs.

Additionally I would also like to have a TAB after :

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution for your problem is use the **Macro** top menu.  Record the change you need for one case, and keep replaying the macro to fix them all.  However, you'll need to figure out a pattern that can be repeated.

Here's another possible solution using Notepad++ Regex.

**Find:** `^(.*)[\r\n]+`

**Replace:** `\1\t`

Comment: that is a pretty long process. Is there a way I can achieve this with regular expressions or extended. The other solutions on stackoverflow does not pertain to my exact requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled over your question: here is a regexp approach that does not need the Macro:

**Find:** `([^\t]*?)\r\n([^\t]*?)\r\n`

**Replace:** `\1\t\2\r\n`

It works because we can match everything before the linebreak for two lines **and we can distinguish** lines that are already processed by the tab character.

It would not work, if the tab is present in the original lines. Then the regexp would match "recursively" and would join everything in one long line.